# A joint model for two continuous outcomes

Tags: r, regression, multivariate-analysis

I have difficulties fitting a joint model in `R`. My data consists of two responses `X` & `Y` and one predictor variable `Z`. Now I want to model both `X` and `Y` in function of `Z` (just linear regression: $E(X|Z)=Z\alpha$ and $E(Y|Z)=Z\beta$, both outcomes are normally distributed) but while doing so I also want to estimate the variance covariance matrix since it is the correlation between `X` and `Y` that I am interested in.

I already looked into a couple of functions (`lm`, `mcer`, `lme`) but it doesn't seem to do the trick. Is there something that I am overlooking in a certain package or a new suggestions to try?

Answer (score 1):

By having two linear regression models as defined above, you are implicitly assuming that X and Y are conditionally independent given Z. For starters, you should instead look into [multivariate linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_linear_regression), which should not be confused with **multiple regression**.

In the linear regression context (i.e., general linear model), **multivariate** means multiple outcomes, while **multiple** means multiple inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use copula models. Refer this article https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265601371_Joint_analysis_of_mixed_discrete_and_continuous_outcomes_via_copula_models